# How to chage the highlighting color of asynktasks in android studio dracula theme

Tags: android-studio

I'm using the Dracula theme in android Studio, which works fine but it looks weird when, for example, an asynktask is highlighted  I suppose that is around here, but I can't find it,

**Were is the Config option for this?**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ts not highlight but background and here is the option:
 [image]